# Handling JWT Expiration for SocketIO Interactions in a React App

Tags: reactjs, next.js, socket.io, jwt, nestjs

I'm running a Nest.js backend which, amongst more things, handles the authentication of my React app. More specifically, I use JWT authentication with an access token and refresh token pair.

The refresh tokens are stored in a database with an expiration date and a unique JTI set on them. When the user logs in or refreshes their token pair, their old refresh token (if any) is set as obsolete and the new is returned as a httpOnly cookie. The access token is returned as is and is stored in memory on the client with a fairly short ttl. That's basically the gist of it.

On the client side, I store my access token in memory using Zustand, and use SWR hooks for other server data like the user. In my custom fetcher I add the access token as the Authorization header, and I also have an interceptor that attempts to refresh the token once whenever the API responds with a 401 and resends the same request again.

This works great most of the time, except for when it comes to interactions with my SocketIO connected chat, since the access token sometimes expires when a message is sent via socket for example. Now the two solutions that I can think of to this would be to either try and add a similar interceptor for sockets (doubtful if this is possible), or to make sure that the access token regularly is kept refreshed, regardless of regular API calls being made.

The regular refreshing of access tokens seems like a fairly hacky/inconsistent solution to me. It would mean that if the user just leaves the page up without even interacting with it, then the access token would still keep refreshing.

I am sure I am not the only who has stumbled upon this issue, so I greatly appreciate any input anyone may have on it!